# box-shadow removes itself

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of stuck with the following issue:

I have a div .pagebody with a assigned box shadow like this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -2px rgba(71,71,71,0.42);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -2px rgba(71,71,71,0.42);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -2px rgba(71,71,71,0.42);
```

Now i noticed during a testsession (in chrome) that after a little while (couple of page refreshes and clicking some anchors) the boxshadow removes itself (it's still removed after refresh).
When i open the console log within chrome it should still be there but whatever i do i can't get it reappear.

I did some research and tried a bunch of different things to fix this and came to the following conclusion:

When i remove the -moz-box-shadow it reappears again and seem to work fine. When i apply the -moz-box-shadow again it works fine for a couple of clicks again and it's gone again.

Now i found the following fix:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .pagebody {
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -2px rgba(71,71,71,0.42);
    }
}
```

And this works fine (even though it's not the best sollution). Is there anybody that know what could go wrong here? Or maybe have a more clean fix for this problem?

Ps. I copied the pagebody div + css and pasted it in to a new project and there it does the same so it looks like it has nothing to do with the rest of my code.

-edit-

I searched in chrome buglist but untill now i was not able to find a reported bug.
I also forgot to mension i'm making use of Sass.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: might be silly, but could you try to move pefixed properties above non-prefixed one? just put moz-box-shadow one line above - any change?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Took me a bit to find out if it worked but unfortunately still same effect..

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in jsfiddle?

Comment: I made a fiddle exactly like i got it to disfunction locally.
https://jsfiddle.net/f0s7vsax/ I would have to test if i can get the same effect in a fiddle. I forgot to mension: Could it maybe have something to do with the fact that i'm using sass with scout GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like i found the problem. Look like it had something to do with scss. I converted my scss to css and now it works fine.